# acts-as-tagabble-on with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, acts-as-taggable-on

In my Rails app, **Users** have many **projects**, and **projects** have many **spins.**

I'm using the [acts-as-taggable-on gem](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) to enable users to add tags to their spins.

I'm building a feature so I can list all the tags used by a particular user and enable users to filter their projects based on these tags.

According to the documentation, I can add ownership to tags.  But I'm unsure how to apply their example of

```
User.find(:first).posts.tag_counts_on(:tags)
```

to my own application.  My best guess is

```
User.first.projects.join(:spins).tag_count_on("spin.tags")
```

But I get an error `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into String`

Anyone able to help?

Comment: Maybe you could work backwards instead?  Something like Spin.joins(:project => :user).where(users: { id: user_id }).tag_count_on(:tags).  I have not verified if that works or not.  Just a thought.